# Show that a function is limited and constrained?

Tags: general-topology

Given $$\{(x,y) \ \in R^2 \ | \ f(x,y) \le 1 \ , \ g(x) \ge 0 \}$$

how would one reason that it is closed and constrained? The closed part is easy enough. Both these regions contain their "boundary", so they are closed. Thus their intersection must be closed as well...

But how about bounded?

Oh, should be said, both $f(x,y)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous on $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: I assume by constrained you mean bounded. This is false in general. Consider the case in which both $f$ and $g$ are constant.

Comment: Okay, so I should say what the functions are then: f(x,y) = $x^2 + y^2 \le 1$ and $g(x)=x \ge 0$.

Comment: Well, $x^2 + y^2 \le 1$ implies that all points are inside the unit circle, so it is bounded.